# Using of EPSG-defined transformation operations in MathTransform of GeoTools

Tags: coordinate-system, geometry, geotools

I have a Point in the Pulkovo 1942 coordinate system which I want to transform to WGS 84.

Below is my initial approach. Note that I use the CRS.decode(String code, boolean longitudeFirst) to make sure that both coordinate systems are EAST_NORTH axis - attempting to escape axis order issues.

I also make use of the "CRS.findMathTransform()" to identify the necessary set of transformation operations automatically.

```
        double longitude = 114.9416666666834;
        double latitude = 60.71666666713304;
        
        String pulkovo1942 = "EPSG:4284";
        String wgs84 = "EPSG:4326";
        
        GeometryFactory fac = new GeometryFactory();
        Point p = fac.createPoint(new Coordinate(longitude, latitude));

        CoordinateReferenceSystem sourceCRS = CRS.decode(pulkovo1942, true);
        CoordinateReferenceSystem targetCRS = CRS.decode(wgs84, true);
        
        
        AxisOrder axisOrderSource = CRS.getAxisOrder(sourceCRS);
        AxisOrder axisOrderTarget = CRS.getAxisOrder(targetCRS);
        
        System.out.println("Axis source: " + axisOrderSource);
        System.out.println("Axis target: " + axisOrderTarget);
        
        MathTransform mt = CRS.findMathTransform(sourceCRS, targetCRS, false);
        Geometry transformed = JTS.transform(p, mt);
        
        System.out.println(transformed.toText());
```

The results are printed like:

```
Axis source: EAST_NORTH
Axis target: EAST_NORTH
POINT (114.94262572129013 60.71735596327227)
```

This works, more or less. However I get complaints on the precision, that the difference here is about ~50meter compared to the original point.

I am therefore asked to apply a specific Transformation to go from Pulkovo 1942 to WGS 84, more specifically the EPSG:1267 found at epsg.io
https://epsg.io/1267

Apparently this should increase the precision and come down to a ~4 meter difference.

I change the relevant parts of my code to use this specific EPSG transformation, and print the results again:

```
        String transformationEPSGCode = "EPSG:1267"; 
        
        CoordinateOperationAuthorityFactory coordOperationsAuthorityFactory = ReferencingFactoryFinder
                 .getCoordinateOperationAuthorityFactory("EPSG", null);
         
         CoordinateOperation coordOperation = coordOperationsAuthorityFactory.createCoordinateOperation(transformationEPSGCode);

         MathTransform mt = coordOperation.getMathTransform();
         Geometry transformed = JTS.transform(p, mt);

         System.out.println(transformed.toText());
```

The results now are:

```
POINT (65.05718639458475 -119.28101342077196)
```

And here we come to the core of my question/issue;

1. The coordinates have been flipped.

Why is that?

If I had different axis order on my source and target CRS, I could have expected something like this, but they are the same.

Or do I need to supply other parameters to the createCoordinateOperation() to indicate that my source CRS is indeed EAST_NORTH so that this is reflected in the MathTransform I pass to JTS?

I guess if JTS.transform makes use of the original definition of the EPSG CRS definitions it will apply axis order NORTH_EAST for the source crs Pulkovo 1942.

2. Also the values seem "far off" for some reason, so it is not just a pure flip of the coordinates
3. I've seen examples of concatenated MathTransforms, but I am reaching the limit of my skill-level here, and I've not been able to find articles or documentation describing this in any good way.
4. Are there any examples or documentation from GeoTools' side making use of such EPSG-based transformations instead of relying on the findMathTransform() method?

For reference the "default" MathTransform returned has a definition like:

```
CONCAT_MT[PARAM_MT["Ellipsoid_To_Geocentric", 
    PARAMETER["dim", 2], 
    PARAMETER["semi_major", 6378245.0], 
    PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6356863.018773047]], 
  PARAM_MT["Position Vector transformation (geog2D domain)", 
    PARAMETER["dx", 43.822], 
    PARAMETER["dy", -108.842], 
    PARAMETER["dz", -119.585], 
    PARAMETER["ex", 1.455], 
    PARAMETER["ey", -0.761], 
    PARAMETER["ez", 0.737], 
    PARAMETER["ppm", 0.5489999999053197]], 
  PARAM_MT["Geocentric_To_Ellipsoid", 
    PARAMETER["dim", 2], 
    PARAMETER["semi_major", 6378137.0], 
    PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6356752.314245179]]]
```

whilst the MathTransform I create based on the EPSG code has the definition:

```
CONCAT_MT[PARAM_MT["Affine", 
    PARAMETER["num_row", 3], 
    PARAMETER["num_col", 3], 
    PARAMETER["elt_0_0", 0.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_0_1", 1.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_1_0", 1.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_1_1", 0.0]], 
  PARAM_MT["Ellipsoid_To_Geocentric", 
    PARAMETER["dim", 2], 
    PARAMETER["semi_major", 6378245.0], 
    PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6356863.018773047]], 
  PARAM_MT["Coordinate Frame Rotation (geog2D domain)", 
    PARAMETER["dx", 23.92], 
    PARAMETER["dy", -141.27], 
    PARAMETER["dz", -80.9], 
    PARAMETER["ex", 0.0], 
    PARAMETER["ey", -0.35], 
    PARAMETER["ez", -0.82], 
    PARAMETER["ppm", -0.1200000000478596]], 
  PARAM_MT["Geocentric_To_Ellipsoid", 
    PARAMETER["dim", 2], 
    PARAMETER["semi_major", 6378137.0], 
    PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6356752.314245179]], 
  PARAM_MT["Affine", 
    PARAMETER["num_row", 3], 
    PARAMETER["num_col", 3], 
    PARAMETER["elt_0_0", 0.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_0_1", 1.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_1_0", 1.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_1_1", 0.0]]]
```

Also, just FYI, if I attempt to transform the POINT using the transform service available at EPSG.io I get:

```
POINT (114.9424272 60.7174563)
```

Which is approx ~3m away from the original - very good.

Comment: `Below is my initial approach. Note that I use the CRS.decode(String code, boolean longitudeFirst) to make sure that both coordinate systems are EAST_NORTH axis - attempting to escape axis order issues.`  There shouldn't be any axis order issues even without this step, as both epsg:4326 and epsg:4284 are lat/long (orientations North_East)  https://epsg.org/transformation_1267/Pulkovo-1942-to-WGS-84-17.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @nmtoken suggests forcing longitude first if it isn't needed can cause problems. I modified your code to:

```
CoordinateReferenceSystem sourceCRS = CRS.decode(pulkovo1942);
CoordinateReferenceSystem targetCRS = CRS.decode(wgs84);

org.geotools.referencing.CRS.AxisOrder axisOrderSource = CRS.getAxisOrder(sourceCRS);
org.geotools.referencing.CRS.AxisOrder axisOrderTarget = CRS.getAxisOrder(targetCRS);
Point p;
if (axisOrderSource.equals(AxisOrder.EAST_NORTH)) {
  p = fac.createPoint(new Coordinate(longitude, latitude));
} else {
  p = fac.createPoint(new Coordinate(latitude, longitude));
}
```

and added the transform [EPSG:5044](https://epsg.io/4284-5044) (which replaces [EPSG:1267](https://epsg.io/4284-1267)) and I get the following output which looks plausible to me. With the 5044 point being `POINT (60.7174562681763 114.94242731480071)` which seems to match your expected point.

```
default
CONCAT_MT[PARAM_MT["Affine", 
    PARAMETER["num_row", 3], 
    PARAMETER["num_col", 3], 
    PARAMETER["elt_0_0", 0.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_0_1", 1.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_1_0", 1.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_1_1", 0.0]], 
  PARAM_MT["Ellipsoid_To_Geocentric", 
    PARAMETER["dim", 2], 
    PARAMETER["semi_major", 6378245.0], 
    PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6356863.018773047]], 
  PARAM_MT["Position Vector transformation (geog2D domain)", 
    PARAMETER["dx", 43.822], 
    PARAMETER["dy", -108.842], 
    PARAMETER["dz", -119.585], 
    PARAMETER["ex", 1.455], 
    PARAMETER["ey", -0.761], 
    PARAMETER["ez", 0.737], 
    PARAMETER["ppm", 0.5489999999053197]], 
  PARAM_MT["Geocentric_To_Ellipsoid", 
    PARAMETER["dim", 2], 
    PARAMETER["semi_major", 6378137.0], 
    PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6356752.314245179]], 
  PARAM_MT["Affine", 
    PARAMETER["num_row", 3], 
    PARAMETER["num_col", 3], 
    PARAMETER["elt_0_0", 0.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_0_1", 1.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_1_0", 1.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_1_1", 0.0]]]
POINT (60.71735596327227 114.94262572129013)
------------------------------------------
1267
CONCAT_MT[PARAM_MT["Affine", 
    PARAMETER["num_row", 3], 
    PARAMETER["num_col", 3], 
    PARAMETER["elt_0_0", 0.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_0_1", 1.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_1_0", 1.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_1_1", 0.0]], 
  PARAM_MT["Ellipsoid_To_Geocentric", 
    PARAMETER["dim", 2], 
    PARAMETER["semi_major", 6378245.0], 
    PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6356863.018773047]], 
  PARAM_MT["Coordinate Frame Rotation (geog2D domain)", 
    PARAMETER["dx", 23.92], 
    PARAMETER["dy", -141.27], 
    PARAMETER["dz", -80.9], 
    PARAMETER["ex", 0.0], 
    PARAMETER["ey", -0.35], 
    PARAMETER["ez", -0.82], 
    PARAMETER["ppm", -0.1200000000478596]], 
  PARAM_MT["Geocentric_To_Ellipsoid", 
    PARAMETER["dim", 2], 
    PARAMETER["semi_major", 6378137.0], 
    PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6356752.314245179]], 
  PARAM_MT["Affine", 
    PARAMETER["num_row", 3], 
    PARAMETER["num_col", 3], 
    PARAMETER["elt_0_0", 0.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_0_1", 1.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_1_0", 1.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_1_1", 0.0]]]
POINT (60.71745484969368 114.94243230681776)
------------------------------------------
5044
CONCAT_MT[PARAM_MT["Affine", 
    PARAMETER["num_row", 3], 
    PARAMETER["num_col", 3], 
    PARAMETER["elt_0_0", 0.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_0_1", 1.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_1_0", 1.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_1_1", 0.0]], 
  PARAM_MT["Ellipsoid_To_Geocentric", 
    PARAMETER["dim", 2], 
    PARAMETER["semi_major", 6378245.0], 
    PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6356863.018773047]], 
  PARAM_MT["Coordinate Frame Rotation (geog2D domain)", 
    PARAMETER["dx", 23.57], 
    PARAMETER["dy", -140.95], 
    PARAMETER["dz", -79.8], 
    PARAMETER["ex", 0.0], 
    PARAMETER["ey", -0.35], 
    PARAMETER["ez", -0.7899999999999999], 
    PARAMETER["ppm", -0.21999999999522402]], 
  PARAM_MT["Geocentric_To_Ellipsoid", 
    PARAMETER["dim", 2], 
    PARAMETER["semi_major", 6378137.0], 
    PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6356752.314245179]], 
  PARAM_MT["Affine", 
    PARAMETER["num_row", 3], 
    PARAMETER["num_col", 3], 
    PARAMETER["elt_0_0", 0.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_0_1", 1.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_1_0", 1.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_1_1", 0.0]]]
POINT (60.7174562681763 114.94242731480071)
```

Comment: Also you can use `MathTransform mt = CRS.findMathTransform(sourceCRS, targetCRS, "EPSG:5044");` to force a transform to be used.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions and input. I will try to move in the direction similar to your example. However, I need to store the geometry in the db as WGS84 with xy, meaning longitude first. Is there a «flip coordinates» transform that I could apply in such scenario? And would it be correct to flip before or after the «main» transformation?

Comment: GeoTools will handle the axis order automatically for you when it fetches the points

Comment: I attempted to use the CRS.findMathTransform(sourceCRS, targetCRS, epsg) method that you suggested. I am using latest and greatest 27.1

`CoordinateReferenceSystem sourceCRS = CRS.decode(pulkovo1942);
  CoordinateReferenceSystem targetCRS = CRS.decode(wgs84);
  
  String transformationEPSGCode = "EPSG:5044"; 
  MathTransform mt = CRS.findMathTransform(sourceCRS, targetCRS, transformationEPSGCode);
`
But this throws an exception:
'
org.opengis.referencing.FactoryException: Parameter "operations[0]" is missing
'

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this a bug with this release?

Comment: Well actually it is a WARNING, not an ERROR - so I assume this is for some legacy transformation codes only.

Comment: I'll have a look tomorrow, I don't think it should throw an exception